# How to get V8 heap snapshot in AWS NodeJS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, memory-leaks

Searching for the best solution to create a heap snapshot from AWS Lambda written in NodeJS. Tried to call V8 heap utilities. Statistics works but as soon as I want to get a dump, it hangs:

```
  // THIS WORKS.
  console.log("Heap space stats = ", v8.getHeapSpaceStatistics())
  console.log("Heap code stats heapdump = ", v8.getHeapCodeStatistics())
  console.log("Heap stats = ", v8.getHeapStatistics())

  // THIS HANGS.
  console.log("Getting heapdump...")
  const snapshotStream = v8.getHeapSnapshot()
```

Any idea why? Is this even possible in the context of AWS Lambda? Any alternative - I'd really like to get memory details, not just stats?

Comment: Hi. I got it working - can you check this repo and tell me what's different in your code ? https://github.com/vdesaintpern/lambda-heap-dump-to-s3-v8

Comment: @vivien.destpern can you please put you repo back online ?